# Priority Queue with custom comparator

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue

I am trying to use a priority queue to hold a custom objected with the following member variables:

```
class Jobs{
    string id;
    string location;
    int start;
    int end;
};
```

I will be reading from file a hashmap of Job ID and the weight of the job. I will ultimately have a

```
unordered_map<string, int> jobWeight;
```

holding this information. I want to push a list of Jobs into a priority_queue eventually with the priority based on the hashmap jobWeight. The highest weighted job should come first.

Referring to other tutorials, I noticed that you should create a separate class/struct and implement the operator(). Then you would pass in this comparison class into the priority_queue parameters. However, it appears that the priority_queue creates a new instance of this comparator class with default parameters? How would I be able to reference my jobWeight hashmap from within this comparator class?

```
class CompareJobs{

    map<string, int> jobWeight;

public:

    CompareJobs(map<string, int> &jobWeight){
        jobWeight = jobWeight;
    }

    bool operator () (const Jobs &a, const Jobs &b){

        return jobWeight.find(a)->second < jobWeight.find(b)->second;

    }

};
```

Comment: You initially stated that `jobWeight` was an `unordered_map`. You want to convert it to a `map` and pass it as an argument to your comparator or what?

Comment: Is this map used for anything else than this comparator? And: How large is it?

Comment: @DanielJour The map should only be used for comparison when I am inserting into my priority queue. The map will be as big as the number of jobs..(every job will have a weight) so could be super large. Currently, the ultimate goal is to select a job for every time frame (the jobs don't have to persist through the whole duration from start to end...so a greedy approach for chosing jobs should be enough. I am just using the priority_queue to fill up the whole range of time frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::priority_queue`'s default constructor actually takes optional parameters:

```
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& x = Compare(), Container&& = Container());
```

You will note that the first parameter is an instance of the comparator class.

Construct your comparator class first, making it reference your hashmap in whatever way is convenient for you, then use the comparator class to construct your priority queue.

Comment: ah never noticed this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

> How would I be able to reference my jobWeight hashmap from within this comparator class?

Add a reference to the map to your Compare class! Of course you need to make sure that this reference stays valid. And you cannot use a plain reference (as these are not copy-able, which your Compare class must be) but instead can use a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

```
using IDMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>;

struct JobsByWeight {
  std::reference_wrapper<IDMap const> weights_ref;
  bool operator()(Job const & lhs, Job const & rhs) const {
    auto const & weights = weights_ref.get();
    auto lhsmapping = weights.find(lhs.id);
    auto rhsmapping = weights.find(rhs.id);
    if (lhsmapping == weights.end() || rhsmapping == weights.end()) {
      std::cerr << "damn it!" << std::endl;
      std::exit(1);
    }
    return lhsmapping->second < rhsmapping->second;
  }
};
```

Then just pass an object of your Compare class to your [priority queue's constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) (overload *(1)* in the link):

```
std::priority_queue<Job, std::vector<Job>, JobsByWeight> queue{std::cref(that_id_map)};
```

Since there's no constructor that allows you to move your Compare class in the queue you really need a reference in `JobsByWeight`. Otherwise there'd be a copy of your map (which could be huge, as you said).

*Note: Untested code.*

Comment: Thanks for this! Never realized priority_queues took parameters.